# Вопрос по работе Docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports:введите сюда код
      - "9090:9090"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY index.php /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 9090
```

```php
<?php
    echo "Hello, world!";
?>
```

Пожалуйста подскажите почему не отрабатывает http://localhost:9090/
http://joxi.ru/gmvG404f0QopG2
Файлы  http://joxi.ru/Rmzl404HVde6lA

Answer (score 1):

Давайте кое что поправим.

Во-первых Dockerfile обязательно должен содержать либо CMD-инструкцию, либо ENTRYPOINT-инструкцию. В вашем случае - запустить веб-сервер Апач.

Во-вторых зачем вам проброс порта 9090 в контейнер? Уберите инструкцию EXPOSE, она вам сейчас не нужна.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY index.php /var/www/html/
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Теперь поправим docker-composer. Мы пробросим с хост-машины порт 9090 внутрь контейнера на порт 80:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
```

В общем-то все.

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

и смотрим что получилось:

```
$ docker ps
```

должно быть что-то вроде:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                PORTS                                                                  NAMES
e2598ade6449   tmp_myapp                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes          0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp, :::9090->80/tcp                                  tmp_myapp_1
```

Ну остается только сделать http://localhost:9090

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: спасибо много, можно просто отметить ответ как полезный ))) Про EXPOSE - это порты, которые нужно прокинуть в контейнер, а не те, которые снаружи. По-умолчанию веб-сервер внутри контейнера на 80 порту. Вот в докер-композере и определим внешний порт 9090 который пробросим внутрь на 80. Обратите внимание на CMD - нам же нужно запустить веб-сервер в контейнере, чтобы он отвечал, верно? Ну и далее, позднее вам понадобиться обновлять код в контейнере без пересборки, тут поможет мануал и всякие статьи